# php7 fail on windows multicore server

Tags: windows, multicore, php-7

My application was getting error of $_GET variable don't exists on Windows 2008 R2 with 4 CPU cores.

So I created this simple code to test.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET)){
    error_log("_GET is not set");
    echo "ERROR";
}else{
    echo "OK";
}
```

And created a simple JMeter test to call it with 15 threads, about 2500 rps.

When I run it in a single core CPU, it works for millions of requests without errors, but when run in a server with 4 CPUs, after about 10,000 requests, the $_GET variable is no more set.

I also repeated the test with $_POST, $_SERVER, $_COOKIE and $_SESSION. And the result was the same.

When downgrade PHP to version 5.6 then it works fine (with 4 CPU).

When set the Apache CPU affinity to a single CPU, it also works.

I'm running:
Apache/2.4.18 (Win64) with PHP/7.0.8.
In a VM with Windows 2008 R2 with 4 CPUs and 4GB of RAM, SSD, hosted at Vultr.com.

Is it a know problem of PHP 7?

Answer (score 1):

What build of PHP are you using ?

From [PHP.net Windows download page](http://windows.php.net/download#php-7.0) :

> Apache
>
> Please use the Apache builds provided by Apache Lounge. They provide VC9, >VC11 and VC14 builds of Apache for x86 and x64. We use their binaries to >build the Apache SAPIs.
>
> If you are using PHP as module with Apache builds from apache.org (not >recommended) you need to use the older VC6 versions of PHP compiled with >the legacy Visual Studio 6 compiler. Do NOT use VC9+ versions of PHP with >the apache.org binaries.
>
> With Apache you have to use the Thread Safe (TS) versions of PHP.

Comment: I'm using version 7.0.8 64 bits thread safe, downloaded from [http://windows.php.net/download#php-7.0](http://windows.php.net/download#php-7.0). And apache from Apache Lounge.